# What is static indexer?

Tags: c#, .net

An interviewer asked me this question, I was puzzled by this term because I understand what a "static" member is and I'm familiar with the concept of an "index" but what exactly is meant `static indexer`? I did some searching of my own but was unable to find a satisfactory definition.

Comment: I'd say it's an indexer that is static, but I understand your confusion. Not sure if that's what your recruiter would've wanted to hear :S

Comment: @hangy I saw that question too, but still it didn't answer the question what I am expecting?? the question posted was 'Why Static indexers is not allowed in C#'?? but my question is 'what is static indexer'? :(

Comment: I don't know if you are aware that there is no stattic indexer in c#. It could be a trick question from your interviewer or he may be trying to size up of your understanding of static access level or indexers.

Answer (score 1):

**static indexer is Not Possible in C#**

Indexer semantics require the 'this' keyword which defines the block of code
as an indexer, and is a also reference to the current instance of a class.
Since a static indexer would have no such reference, it stands to reason that
you can't define an indexer as static. That's just my personal
interpretation, there may be a bigger picture than that.

However, if you have a special need, indexers are just a convenience - you
can accomplish what you want to do the old fashioned way through methods.

The fact of the matter is, however, that indexers can't be defined as static.

Comment: this is just an indication to compiler that this member is a class indexer, you could as well use mars for that place holder and it would serve the same purpose.